# Use ::class notation instead warning while checking code in Magento 2 coding standard

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am accessing block function in phtml like

```
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Esparksinc\Extension\Block\Product\View');
```

but this gave Waring of class notation instead while cheqing code during coding standarded.

Answer (score 6):

Use

> `$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Esparksinc\Extension\Block\Product\View::class`);

**instead of**

> `$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Esparksinc\Extension\Block\Product\View');`

**Or, Add this block using layout.**

Comment: I want to do it in `.phtml` file. Any idea?

Comment: Its works for  `phtml` file as well.

Comment: It should be withing Quotation '\Esparksinc\Extension\Block\Product\View:class'

Comment: it should be `\Esparksinc\Extension\Block\Product\View::class` .Double `::`

Comment: Not required single quote `(`)`

Answer (score 0):

Bacically block is attached with its phtml so we can directly call block function from phtml so there is no need to create the block object at all like.

```
$block->callBlockFunction();
```